# Is there a built in way to create a file if it doesn't exist when opening one?

Tags: c#, file-io, io

I need to open a file to write some text to it, is there a built in way where the file is created if it doesn't exist already?

I want to append to this file, and avoid locking it while it is open.  But I will be writing to the file if there is an exeption in a loop like:

```
try
{

}
catch()
{
  write to file
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`File.Open`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc65tk0x.aspx) with a [`FileMode.OpenOrCreate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode.aspx), [`FileMode.Append`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode.aspx).

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.Append)) 
{
    // use fs
}
```

In either case, if the file has been opened with `FileAccess.Write` or `FileAccess.ReadWrite`, a new file will be created if one doesn't exist.

Comment: FileMode.Append also creates the file if it doesn't exist and fits OP requirements better.

Comment: I want to write text to the file, append text.

Comment: @codecompleting - I suggest reading the links I put in my answer.

Comment: didn't realize them were links.

Answer (score 1):

```
var fileStream = new FileStream(@"c:\file.txt", FileMode.Append);
```

This will create the file, if it doesnt exist already.

Comment: You should wrap the creation of the stream in a `using` statement to ensure proper disposal.